# Outputting my local storage using JavaScript on startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Making a simple task tracking application, I've just implemented local storage to the app and am struggling to output the stored information. The information that is stored is correct when I check in the chrome console.

The code below is how I store the data and how I currently outputted the inputted data from the user.

```
var taskItem = "<div class='task-item'><h1 class='task-name'>" + name + "
</h1><h1 class='task-date'>" + date + "</h1><h1 class='task-assigned'>" + 
assigned + "</h1></div>";   //Current output of inputted data from user

localStorage.setItem("Lname", JSON.stringify(name));  //storing the 
                                                      //inputted data
localStorage.setItem("Ldate", JSON.stringify(date));
localStorage.setItem("Lassigned", JSON.stringify(assigned));

$(".task-wrapper").prepend(taskItem)
```

What I'm trying to do now is output the local storage on the next boot up of the app. Any pointers would be really quite helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
localStorage.getItem("Lname");
```

to retrieve your data.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Answer (score 0):

In my applications I use this little program!
Try it ..

```
var DB = function(){
    this.Read = function(index){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage[index]).data;
    };

    this.Write = function(index, data){
        localStorage[index] = JSON.stringify({data : data});
    };

    this.Test = function(){ // test support localStorage!
        return typeof localStorage == typeof {};
    };

    this.Clear = function(index){
      if(typeof index === "undefined"){
        localStorage = {};
      } else {
        localStorage[index] = JSON.stringify({data : []});
      }
    };
}
```

**example:**

```
var x = new DB(); // new data base
if(!x.Test()) alert('Error!'); // not support!
x.Write('food', ['food','bar','google']); // write data
console.log(x.Read('food')); // get data!

x.Clear('food'); // clear data!
console.log(x.Read('food')); // get data!
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now, thank you all for helping!

I had to use to get the data from the local storage.

```
Rname = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('Lname'))
```

Thanks.